# ¿Por qué mi resultado me da 0?

Tags: java, float, set

Cunado pongo mi variable float (radio) en privado y al invocarla en las clase principal, cuando ejecuto el programa que me pide solo un dato (el radio de un circulo) pero los datos que devuelve son puros ceros. Esto no pasa si la variable no es privada
Ayuda porfavor

**Clase PerimetroYarea**

```
package perimetroyarea;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class PerimetroYarea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Circulo circulo = new Circulo();
        //Pedir datos al usuario

             circulo.setRadio(Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Perimetro: ")));
        //Devolver datos
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, circulo.toString());
    }
    
}
```

**Clase Circulo**

```
package perimetroyarea;

public class Circulo {
    private float radio;
   
    public double perimetroCirculo(){
        return (radio*2)*(3.1416);
    }
    
    public double areaCirculo(){
        return 3.1416 * (radio*radio);
    }

    public float getRadio() {
        return radio;
    }

    public void setRadio(float r) {
        r = radio;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Tu perimetro es de: "+perimetroCirculo()
                +"\nTu área es de: "+areaCirculo();
    }
     
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! de que variable hablas?

Comment: Un consejo: evita usar el tipo `float`en Java: por defecto, cualquier operación en punto flotante devuelve un valor `double` que vas a tener que *castear* a float para poder guardarlo y el esfuerzo no vale la pena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu problema se encuentra en la logica de tu `setter`

```
 public void setRadio(float r) {
        r = radio;
    }
```

`r` es el dato que capturas con el `inputDialog` pero radio es 0 ,en otras palabras estas diciendo que r sea igual a 0,lo correcto es decir que radio siendo 0 sea igual r que es el que tiene el valor recibido en el input

```
public void setRadio(float r) {
            radio = r;
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta